# File upload to AppEngine Blobstore

Tags: java, google-app-engine, gwt

Following this [blobstore document](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/blobstore/overview) on how to upload to the Blobstore. It shows uploading through JSP + Servlet approach.

Since my app is based on GWT, I need to adapt the for GWT RPC (instead of JSP).

So in my app RPC  service implementation:

```
public class MyServiceImpl extends RemoteServiceServlet implements
    MyService {

  public String getUploadUrl() {
    BlobstoreService blobstoreService = BlobstoreServiceFactory.getBlobstoreService();
    return blobstoreService.createUploadUrl("/upload")
  }
}
```

Is this the right approach or is there any other way to do it properly? I haven't tried this code though.

The binary that will be uploaded range from bytes to 2MB at max.

Following this [blobstore document](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/blobstore/overview) on how to upload to the Blobstore. It shows uploading through JSP + Servlet approach.

Since my app is based on GWT, I need to adapt the for GWT RPC (instead of JSP).

So in my app RPC  service implementation:

```
public class MyServiceImpl extends RemoteServiceServlet implements
    MyService {

  public String getUploadUrl() {
    BlobstoreService blobstoreService = BlobstoreServiceFactory.getBlobstoreService();
    return blobstoreService.createUploadUrl("/upload")
  }
}
```

Is this the right approach or is there any other way to do it properly? I haven't tried this code though.

The binary that will be uploaded range from bytes to 2MB at max.

When I tried out this code, this is the server side console log:

```
May 07, 2012 6:35:53 AM com.google.appengine.tools.development.LocalResourceFileServlet doGet
WARNING: No file found for: /crossdomain.xml
```

Then on the client side GWT.log the Rpc was able to generate a URL however it does not work:

```
[INFO] [blobrpc] - Success fetch upload url: http://127.0.0.1:8888/_ah/upload/aglub19hcHBfaWRyGwsSFV9fQmxvYlVwbG9hZFNlc3Npb25fXxgDDA
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`createUploadUrl()` creates a Url that expects a HTTP POST with Content-type header `multipart/form-data`.

If you want to use GWT-RPC than you need to use [Blobstore FileService API](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/blobstore/overview#Writing_Files_to_the_Blobstore) to create file on server side.

Comment: I see, but if I use FormElement form = Document.get().createFormElement(); form.setAction(url_from_rpc); Is this valid? Or the application will get some Session problem with this approach?

Comment: I managed to write a working code with the aid of the Blobstore FileService API, though I need to write some ways to process streaming file upload. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: `gwtupload` project has some server-side support for GAE including streaming: http://code.google.com/p/gwtupload/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2FGwtUpload%2Fgae%2Fsrc%2Fmain%2Fjava%2Fgwtupload%2Fserver%2Fgae

Answer (score 0):

If we were to post a file to that URL, it would be saved in blobstore. Note however that the default URL for the local development web server is http://127.0.0.1:8888/ while the URL generated by blobstore is http://:8888/. This will cause problems later on, as for security reasons Plupload won't be able to POST files to another domain. This only happens with the local development server, the published app will have only one URL. Fix it by editing the Run Configurations in Eclipse, add -bindAddress  to the arguments. This will cause the local development server to host the web app on http://:8888/ instead. You might need to allow  in the GWT browser plugin for it to load the app after this change.

[Multiple file upload using GWT and AppEngine Blobstore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14140483/multiple-file-upload-using-gwt-and-appengine-blobstore)