# How to get uploaded excel file from blobstore and how to assign that file to FileInputStream

Tags: java, gwt, fileinputstream

I am working on project using GWT Java. I uploaded excel file into blobstore in google app engine. I want to read excel file from blobstore. So I have to assign the that excel file from blobstore to FileInputStream.

Example:

```
 FileInputStream file = new FileInpuStream("what is path shall i provide here")
```

What are the possible ways to assign that excel file from blobstore to FileInputStream? 
Any help?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Can you include code snippet in which you are reading Excel file into a blob?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Apache POI to open the Excel File using your `FileInputStream` with for example:

```
XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(new FileInputStream(<whatever>));
```

and work with the POI API to modify the Excelsheet or get the cellinfos. More information to Apache POI: [click here](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html).

Or to see a similar problem on SO:[click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17556108/open-existing-xls-in-apache-poi)

Comment: Thanks MrT but how shall i assign that excel to FileInputStream from blob? means what is path shall i provide FileinputStream. means in the place of <whatever>

Comment: Have a look [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Blob.html) and try out `getBinaryStream()` to write the Stram to a File and use this.

Answer (score 0):

The Apache POI `XSSFWorkbook` accepts either a `File` or an `InputStream`.
Assuming that you can access your Blob object via `BlobstoreInputStream` instance, you can call:

```
 // BlobKey blobKey = initialize your blob key
 XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(new BlobstoreInputStream(blobKey));
```

You can access the `Blobstore` via:

```
public class Upload extends HttpServlet {
    private BlobstoreService blobstoreService = BlobstoreServiceFactory.getBlobstoreService();

    @Override
    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
        Map<String, List<BlobKey>> blobs = blobstoreService.getUploads(req);
        List<BlobKey> blobKeys = blobs.get("myFile");

        if (blobKeys != null && !blobKeys.isEmpty()) {
            XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(new BlobstoreInputStream(blobKeys.get(0)));
        }
    }
}
```

Further reading: [Blobstore Java API Overview](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/blobstore/#Writing_Files_to_the_Blobstore)

Comment: I've extended the sample. Hope this helps to solve your case.

Comment: Thanks Maciej we are not using servlets in GWT so where shall i try this code ? shall i make RPC call or shall i create new class on server side? I am new in gwt so could you please explain me in detail

Comment: Check this [SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10472244/file-upload-to-appengine-blobstore). This should help with the GWT.

Comment: I tried this  but  XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(BlobstoreInputStream(blobKey));  it shows error for BlobstoreInputStream  The method BlobstoreInputStream(BlobKey) is undefined.   any solution?

Comment: This should be a call to constructor:  `XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(new BlobstoreInputStream(blobKey));`. Fixed in posted answer.

Comment: In eclipse it gives suggestion to create method BlobstoreInputStream(blobKey) if i tried to fix it. It created method with return null

Comment: You have to call `BlobstoreInputStream(blobKey)` constructor, not to create a new method as suggested per Eclipse.

Comment: Thanks a lot  Maciej Lach i fixed it. but i did not get that how shall i get my blob key because I am working with GWT  I can not use request object. any help Thanks in advance